# Flutter: Unexpected null value on setting custom theme

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to add a custom theme but getting unexpected null value error. Here is `main.dart`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'theme/custom_theme.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'My App',
      theme: CustomTheme.lightTheme(context),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('MyApp'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: const [
              Text('Some text'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and `custom_theme.dart`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import './palette.dart';

class CustomTheme {

  static ThemeData lightTheme(BuildContext context) {
    final theme = Theme.of(context);
    return ThemeData(
      brightness: Brightness.light,
      primarySwatch: MaterialColor(
        Palette.color500.value,
        const {
          100: Palette.color100,
          200: Palette.color200,
          300: Palette.color300,
          400: Palette.color400,
          500: Palette.color500,
          600: Palette.color600,
          700: Palette.color700,
          800: Palette.color800,
          900: Palette.color900,
        },
      ),
      accentColor: Palette.color500,
      scaffoldBackgroundColor: Palette.almostBlack,
      appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(
        elevation: 0,
        color: Palette.almostBlack,
      ),
      sliderTheme: SliderThemeData(
        activeTrackColor: Colors.white,
        inactiveTrackColor: Colors.grey.shade800,
        thumbColor: Colors.white,
        valueIndicatorColor: Palette.color500,
        inactiveTickMarkColor: Colors.transparent,
        activeTickMarkColor: Colors.transparent,
      ),
      textTheme: theme.primaryTextTheme
          .copyWith(
            button: theme.primaryTextTheme.button?.copyWith(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 16,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          )
          .apply(
            displayColor: Colors.white,
          ),
      textButtonTheme: TextButtonThemeData(
        style: TextButton.styleFrom(
          backgroundColor: Palette.color500,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

If I use dark theme then that works without any issues:

```
darkTheme: CustomTheme.darkTheme(context),
```

This is what it shows in the debug console:

Logs

```dart
Launching lib/main.dart on Chrome in debug mode...
This app is linked to the debug service: ws://127.0.0.1:58117/dNblBnvWHDA=/ws
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:58117/dNblBnvWHDA=/ws
 Running with sound null safety 
Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:58117/dNblBnvWHDA=/ws
Flutter Web Bootstrap: Programmatic
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following TypeErrorImpl was thrown building MyApp(dirty):
Unexpected null value.
The relevant error-causing widget was:
  MyApp
MyApp:file:///Users/chinmaysarupria/gegobyte_technologies_private_limited/Flutter%20Apps/financial_calculator/lib/main.dart:6:16
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 251:49      throw_
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 528:63  nullCheck
packages/flutter/src/material/theme_data.dart 517:76                              new
packages/financial_calculator/theme/custom_theme.dart 61:12                       lightTheme
packages/financial_calculator/main.dart 16:26                                     build
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4876:22                               build
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4806:15                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4529:5                                rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4787:5                                [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4781:5                                mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3817:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3551:18                               updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart 1202:16                                 [_rebuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart 1171:5                                  mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart 1119:16                                 <fn>
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 2597:19                               buildScope
packages/flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart 1118:12                                 attachToRenderTree
packages/flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart 952:24                                  attachRootWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart 933:7                                   <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/isolate_helper.dart 48:19           internalCallback
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to show the full Traceback?

Answer (score 0):

The appbar theme constructor is deprecated. You can probably try copying it

```dart
appBarTheme: AppBarTheme.copyWith(
        elevation: 0,
        color: Palette.almostBlack,
      ),
```

> Constructors
> AppBarTheme({@Deprecated('This property is no longer used, please use systemOverlayStyle instead. ' 'This feature was deprecated after v2.4.0-0.0.pre.') Brightness? brightness, Color? color, Color? backgroundColor, Color? foregroundColor, double? elevation, double? scrolledUnderElevation, Color? shadowColor, Color? surfaceTintColor, ShapeBorder? shape, IconThemeData? iconTheme, IconThemeData? actionsIconTheme, @Deprecated('This property is no longer used, please use toolbarTextStyle and titleTextStyle instead. ' 'This feature was deprecated after v2.4.0-0.0.pre.') TextTheme? textTheme, bool? centerTitle, double? titleSpacing, double? toolbarHeight, TextStyle? toolbarTextStyle, TextStyle? titleTextStyle, SystemUiOverlayStyle? systemOverlayStyle, @Deprecated('This property is obsolete and is false by default. ' 'This feature was deprecated after v2.4.0-0.0.pre.') bool? backwardsCompatibility})
> Creates a theme that can be used for ThemeData.appBarTheme.
> const